# Why am I a penguin when I should be a microwave?

Tags: goat-simulator

As you can see, I am a penguin (*see area marked '1' for clarification*):

[image: Unexpected Penguin]

However, I am expecting to be a Microwave, since this is Goat Simulator. Areas 2 & 3 clearly show the expected Microwave profile icon and related *Pizza* and *Explode* powers.

I don't know how or why this happened but I think it occurred after I clipped through the landscape and then respawned. I'm genuinely not sure if something went wrong or if this is an expected part of the game.

Has anyone seen this before and is there an actual explanation for this? Perhaps it's a default model loaded when the Microwave model is not found? Does it signify any game state or rule change?

Please note that the enchanted sword balanced on the penguin's head is supposed to be there.

Comment: In general, there really isn't an explanation for things in goat simulator. One of the things that makes it so popular is how random it is.

Comment: +1 For title and picture... I have no idea why you're getting this. It's very likely you hit some kind of bug. But I know for the most part the game is riddled with little bugs like this. The developers fully acknowledge these bugs and have no intention on fixing these because they are absolutely hilarious.

Comment: Who cooks pizza in a microwave?!

Comment: What the hell happened to this game since I last tried it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The penguin is the "Classy Goat" modifier.** When you have modifiers on, you can experience many weird occurrences, due to many overlapping. In this case, you at least have the "Classy Goat" and "Microwave" modifier enabled.

**"Classy Goat" unlocks by picking up 10 goat statues in Goat City Bay.**

**To disable (or enable) modifiers, simply click on them in the level select.** The left side lists available modifiers, and the right side lists currently loaded modifiers. Clicking on an entry moves it to the other list.

[image]

Comment: I figured this out independently - my exact situation was that I had the Classy Goat mutator but as I chose the Microwave class I initially spawned as a microwave. Then, when I had to respawn manually, the Classy Goat mutator must have taken priority and got loaded instead. And yet it used the microwave textures! (mostly white with some black highlights/dots). The key here is "weird occurrences", which you mentioned.